# Wordpress Table Max Width in mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, width

Really struggling with the can't find a definitive answer on this. Trying to help my local community by promoting a list of business that are still operating during the covid-19 outbreak.

My problem is that the table width in mobile view looks awful and basically chops off the last column. Please can you advise any css I could use to correct this?

See https://www.larklaneguide.com/delivery-and-takeaway-on-lark-lane-during-covid-19/

TIA

Clare

Comment: That's all you can do with tables.  It's mobile friendly, as you can touch to scroll it left/right.  Unless you made a fully responsive grid, or something like this https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Ok thanks, sounds easier to do that than fiddling with code. I appreciate the suggestion :)